# How to fetch the size of specific folder in IMAP client using C#

Tags: c#, .net

Previously I have tried to get size of folders by looping through messages and reading the message and attachment sizes. Summing those sizes and displaying as a folder size.

If we have more than 10 messages in a folder it takes a lot of time to loop through all messages. According to my requirement I have to calculate total size of folder directly using C#.

Please help me.

Comment: mail manipulation is often a harder task.. So, what do you have as code, what specifically other than "slow" is it having issues with and what have you tried?

Comment: Cleaned up grammer

Comment: Unfortunately `IMAP4Rev1` does not provide this functionality. What I suggest is to use the `FETCH` command fetching only `RFC822.SIZE` to only retrieve message sizes when fetching (e.g. `a FETCH 1:* RFC822.SIZE`); this may improve performance unless that's already what you're doing. Link to [RFC3501](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501).